# Convert Int to Double in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
label.text = String(format:"%.1f hour", theOrder.bookingMins/60.0)
```

The above code returns this error:

> 'Int' is not convertible to 'Double'

`bookingMins` is of type Int, so how do I convert an Int to a Double in Swift? Seems not as simple as in C.

Comment: This is *documented* behaviour of the Swift programming language to avoid hidden conversion errors. I would recommend to read the chapter "Numeric Type Conversion" in the Swift reference book.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Try `Double(theOrder.bookingMins)`

Comment: Double(theOrder.bookingMins!)/60.0 solve the problem. strange!

Comment: @shadow: `Double(theOrder.bookingMins/60.0)` doesn't work since `bookingMins` is an Int, but you're trying to divide it by a double (60.0). You _first_ have to convert `bookingMins` via `Double(theOrder.bookingMins)`, then you can divide by 60.0 since only then both are of the same type.

Comment: Seems like this long explanation should be included in the answer, which sadly is still devoid of any explanation whatsoever.

Answer (score 9):

What I prefer to do is to use computed properties. So I like to create an extension of Double and than add a property like below:

```
extension Int {
  var doubleValue: Double {
    return Double(self)
  }
}
```

And than you can use it in very Swifty way, I believe in future updates of swift language will be something similar.

```
let bookingMinutes = theOrder.bookingMins.doubleValue
```

in your case

```
label.text = String(format: "%.1f hour", bookingMinutes / 60.0)
```

Style guide used: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Answer (score 4):

```
label.text = String(format:"%.1f hour", Double(theOrder.bookingMins) /60.0)
```